# Uncaught ReferenceError: cordovaHTTP is not defined

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using Cordova 5.1.1 on Android with [CordovaHTTP plugin](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP). I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: cordovaHTTP is not defined. I insert this script in the body of my index page, after the cordova.js reference.

```
cordovaHTTP.get("https://google.com/", {
            id: 12,
            message: "test"
        }, { Authorization: "OAuth2: token" }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.status);
            alert(respose.status);
        }, function(response) {
            console.error(response.error);
            alert(response.error);
        });
```

Comment: Sounds like the `cordovaHTTP` plugin isn't properly installed. Did you inject it as an Angular dependency if you're using Angular? Otherwise, try removing it and re-adding it with `cordova plugin add https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP.git`?

Comment: Yes, It was a problem of the plugin. I removed it and the re-installed. Now it works. Thanks